# log4j.xml in Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, log4j

Which is the best place to keep `log4j.xml` in eclipse folders? I keep it under `\build\classes`
however every time when I clean project, `log4j.xml` gets removed.

So what is the standard and best place to keep `log4j.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\build\classes` is the target folder of the project, you should put `log4j.xml` in the source folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks, I moved to `\src` folder and looks alright after clean.

Answer (score 2):

In a Maven-standard build config, you put it in `src/main/resources`, but anywhere in the root of the classpath is fine, e.g. `src/main/java`, `src/java`, whatever.  Just don't put it in a directory containing generated artifacts (like `build/classes`), since it'll be deleted every time you blink.